# Почему в Spring Boot и Hibernate не работает по умолчанию Naming strategy?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot

Открываю [официальную документацию](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-access.configure-hibernate-naming-strategy) по Spring Boot и вижу, что Spring Boot по умолчанию использует стратегию именования `SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy`, которая принадлежит Hibernate и подразумевает правила:

- все точки заменяются символами подчеркивания
- регистр camelCase заменяется также подчеркиванием
- по умолчанию все имена таблиц создаются в нижнем регистре. Например, объект `TelephoneNumber` отображается в таблицу `phone_number`.

Есть у меня сущность `GiftCertificate`. Почему при выполнении запроса через EntityManager мой Entity-класс c именем `GiftCertificate` переименовывается в `giftcertificate`, а не в `gift_certificate`, как ожидается?

На всякий случай привожу пример:

- запрос в БД:

```java
    @Override
    public Set<GiftCertificate> findAll() {
        return entityManager.createQuery(FIND_ALL_GIFT_CERTIFICATES_SQL, GiftCertificate.class)
                .getResultStream()
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
```

Результат - `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'gift_certificates_system_db.giftcertificate' doesn't exist`

- сущность `GiftCertificate`:

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@EntityListeners(GiftCertificateListener.class)
public class GiftCertificate implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private BigDecimal price;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer duration;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime createDate;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private LocalDateTime lastUpdateDate;
}
```

- Конфигурация:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class EsmConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private final DataSource dataSource;

    @Autowired
    public EsmConfiguration(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITY_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messages = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messages.setBasename("locale");
        messages.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        messages.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return messages;
    }

    @Bean
    public MethodValidationPostProcessor methodValidationPostProcessor() {
        return new MethodValidationPostProcessor();
    }
}
```

Что я пробовал:

- в `application.properties` указывал явно `spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl`, но не помогает.
- явно указывать `@Table(name = "gift_certificate")` - помогает, но меня интересует реализация по умолчанию без явного указания имен таблиц в куче сущностей, что загромождает код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ImplicitNamingStrategy` используется, когда явно не указывается имя базы данных, имя таблицы, имя столбца в определении сущности. Т.е. когда не используется аннотация `@Table` или если есть аннотация `@Column`, но свойство `name` не задано.

`PhysicalNamingStrategy` стратегия вступает в работу, когда явно задано имя БД, имя таблицы, имя столбца, например `@Column(name = "camelCase")`. Вот тогда Hibernate уже будет работать со значением параметра `name`.

Задаются свойства в `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy
```

Мне нужно была стратегия `ImplicitNamingStrategy`, а не `PhysicalNamingStrategy`.